# Как добавить второй обработчик Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

Здраствуйте, есть сайт на Bitrix, сам с битрикс работаю впервые, у меня есть покупка на сайте, как сделать второй обработчик создания заказа? Чтоб после заказа срабатывало два события.

Как такое сделать?

Comment: зарегистрировать 2 обработчика события)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хоть 2, хоть 22 обработчика используйте.
Просто нужно зарегистрировать их как и первый.

```
use \Bitrix\Main; 
Main\EventManager::getInstance()->addEventHandler(
    'sale',
    'OnSaleOrderSaved',
    'myFunctionOne'
);
Main\EventManager::getInstance()->addEventHandler(
    'sale',
    'OnSaleOrderSaved',
    'myFunctionTwo'
);

function myFunctionOne() {

}

function myFunctionTwo() {

}
```

Вместо OnSaleOrderSaved можно использовать другое событие заказа.